# Why is trim() not removing the leading space in my Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a weather station app using the OpenWeather API and VueJS. To set the weather icon, I'm using `owf-font`, which you use in a similar way to FontAwesome by setting a CSS class using a code supplied by the API.

I am grabbing the next 5 hours of data from the API and storing them in an array. So, I assign my icon code like this:

```
this.iconCode.push(String(response.data.list[i].weather[0].id).trim());
```

Then I assign the class in the template:

```
<i :class="['owf owf-',iconCode[0]]"></i>
```

But this is rendered as:

```
<i class="owf owf- 500"></i>
```

I have also tried:

```
<i :class="['owf owf-',iconCode[0].trim()]"></i>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update `['owf owf-',iconCode[0]]` to `['owf owf-'+iconCode[0]]`

Comment: when you used `,` you added 2 items to array and vue added 2 "classes:" `owf owf-` and `500` with space between

Comment: So simple! Put that as answer and I'll happy accept it.

Comment: It's easy to miss :) I've added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
['owf owf-',iconCode[0]]
```

to

```
['owf owf-'+iconCode[0]]
```

So `,` to `+`

`trim()` is working fine, but when you used `,` you added 2 items to array and vue added 2 classes

`owf owf-` and `500` with **space** in between.